# Jquery autocomplete with multiple words

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am working on jquery, i have a textbox with autocomplete , it is working for single word but when i type second word into that textbox the first one gets disappper.

Suppose first i have typed **Java** and then **Java Script** , the first **Java** gets disappered from the textbox.

Here is the code,

```
<script>
$("#tag").autocomplete( {
    source: "http://localhost:8080/autocomp",
        multiple: true,
        mustMatch: true,
        autoFill: true
    });
</script>
```

Textbox should have text like **Java**, **Javascript**

Comment: Would you be so kind to put it in a jsFiddle?

Comment: Will you please explain ? Thanks

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net is a nifty website which allows us to tinker with the code, without us having to recreate it ourselves. You can put you relevant code in there, that way we can work on the exact situation you have.

Comment: Please look at the [multiple values demo](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple-remote) on jQueryUI's website.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the source. 
source: "http://localhost:8080/autocomp"

Try adding values into a variable or get the source in a different way.

Comment: I have changed the source , still having same problem

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but it came up high in the search rankings when I had the same problem. This is supported in jQuery > 1.8. [Their example](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple) is:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC",
        "C",
        "C++",
        "Clojure",
        "COBOL",
        "ColdFusion",
        "Erlang",
        "Fortran",
        "Groovy",
        "Haskell",
        "Java",
        "JavaScript",
        "Lisp",
        "Perl",
        "PHP",
        "Python",
        "Ruby",
        "Scala",
        "Scheme"];

    function split(val) {
        return val.split(/,\s*/);
    }

    function extractLast(term) {
        return split(term).pop();
    }
    $("#tags")
    // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
    .bind("keydown", function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB && $(this).data("ui-autocomplete").menu.active) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    })
        .autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: function (request, response) {
            // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
            response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(
            availableTags, extractLast(request.term)));
        },
        focus: function () {
            // prevent value inserted on focus
            return false;
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            var terms = split(this.value);
            // remove the current input
            terms.pop();
            // add the selected item
            terms.push(ui.item.value);
            // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
            terms.push("");
            this.value = terms.join(", ");
            return false;
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

I've tested this and it works.